# How can I get the Last Successful Build time and Last Failed Build time Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Using the XML API, how can I construct the query string parameters to get the Last Successful Build time and Last Failed Build time for all jobs?

I have "/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,color]" but need these 2 additional field so I can get an overall status of all jobs on the server.

Comment: I know how I can do it a job at a time, but I have many jobs on multiple servers so I don't want to have to call each job individually, I would like to get all jobs from each server in a single call to each server.

Answer (score 3):

you can get it by calling Jenkins server with path:

```
/job/[job name]/lastSuccessfulBuild/

/job/[job name]/lastFailedBuild/
```

Comment: Please see the comment I added to my question

Comment: This may be outdated, I got 404 for `curl --user $JENKINS_USERNAME:$JENKINS_API_TOKEN  "https://jenkins-cicd.americas.company.pvt/job/jobNameHere/lastFailedBuild"`